# How to represent sets of quantities with different units mathematically?

Tags: notation, unit-of-measure

Let's say I have two nonnegative rational quantities – e.g., time and potatoes – that I want to represent by (potentially infinite) sets of elements $T$ and $P$.

What would be a correct mathematical (formal) definition for that?

Intuitively, I would write $T \overset{\text{def}}{=} P \overset{\text{def}}{=} \mathbb{Q}_{\ge0}$;  with $T$ measured in seconds, and $P$ measured in potatoes. Assuming it is a correct way to present it, it is not a formal definition, however$\dots$

Thanks in advance for your answers.

NS

Comment: There are no such thing as a unit of measure as far as mathematics is concerned. We are not physicists.

Comment: You are right; but how would a physicist formally write it in this case?

Comment: Isn't that a question for *physicists*?

Comment: It is indeed. I just learned about physics.stackexchange.